# How do I integrate with the Braintree Payment Gateway using Braintree.js?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, braintree

can anyone know how to configure braintree.js payment gateway.

here is the link to braintree's site.

https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more detail than you can easily get on Stack Overflow, please reach out to our [support team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/support).</sub>

The [Braintree.js docs](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/javascript) walk you through everything from signing up for sandbox to processing transactions. It sounds like you've already done step 1:

> 1. Sign up for a [Sandbox](https://www.braintreepayments.com/get-started) account.
> 2. Follow the [tutorials](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/overview).
> 3. Complete your integration and sandbox testing.
> 4. Go through the [apply process](https://www.braintreepayments.com/signup).
> 5. Test in production.

If you're asking about how to do the technical side, then [our Braintee.js tutorials](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/overview) are definitely the place to start.

Comment: i have already integrated it in my framework. its working fine on the root of the server, but gives an error when i put the braintree library in library folder and the form in my desired location of the framework.
i provide right path of braintree library in my form file, after submitting form it gives an error
'Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_ForgedQueryString'  in /home/logitapp/public_html/videorecording/library/braintree/lib/Braintree/TransparentRedirect.php:269'

Comment: @SharmaArsh I'd suggest reaching out to our [support team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/support). If you do, please try to provide them exact details of your setup, full backtrace, and relevant code so they can best help you with your problem. However, Braintree.js and Transparent Redirect are two different integration methods, it sounds like you're maybe mixing the two up based on your question and comment.

Comment: its working fine now, i investigated in transparent redirect and get that the url string comes with some arbitrary text, after removing it, its working fine and i get the transaction id of payment.

thanks for your time agf.

Comment: I have recently implemented branintree payment with node.js and mongodb. Braintree has provided a good documentation at this. However, imho, it's still not really user friendly as it's a bit scatter. Hence, I have decided to write up an end-to-end integration at 

http://enormers.com/blog/implement-braintree-payment-with-nodejs-and-mongodb/

Let me know if you find this post useful